# How can I share a specific page on flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am doing an event app and I want to share my events. How can i implement eventID's to the my app's url and how can I create url ?

I searched some plugins for share. for example this. https://pub.dev/packages/share.

They are sharing text only. i need url.

Comment: You need to share some code about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put in a url like:

```
Share.share('https://example.com/?eventid=' + event_id):
```